# Facebook Connect for iPhone with a Session Proxy

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

I'm using the Facebook Connect for iPhone SDK at http://github.com/facebook/facebook-iphone-sdk/ and am trying to get the provided demo "Connect" app to work using a [Session Proxy](http://www.performantdesign.com/2009/09/03/facebook-iphone-session-proxy-in-php-fbsession-getsessionproxy/).

The iPhone shows the connect dialogue and gives my server a valid auth token which I pass to facebook. Facebook responds with a valid session key and session secret:

```
<auth_getSession_response xmlns="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/http://api.facebook.com/1.0/facebook.xsd">

    <session_key>32fcxxx</session_key>
    <uid>xxx</uid>
    <expires>0</expires>
    <secret>9f5xxx</secret>
    <base_domain>example.com</base_domain>

</auth_getSession_response>
```

When not using the session proxy (which I need to use) the login works fine. Yet when I try the example using the session proxy, the example application returns with "Canceled login" (sic). No other part of the Facebook connect example codebase has been changed.

Is this a bug with the iPhone SDK or is there something extra I need to do for the iPhone to read the XML my server is returning?

Comment: I'm getting something similar. I had session proxy working and it stopped working a few weeks ago for some strange reason, dialog fails with "canceled login" - tracing the code, NSURLConnection is returning an "unsupported URL" NSError. Are you getting the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this. As I was using Django, I had forgotten to set the proper XML headers required for the iPhone library to parse the response as XML.

tl;dr, make sure that your session proxy is outputting an actual XML file! http://hurl.it/ is great for debugging this sort of thing.